# MongoDB Aggregation converts properties type of array to string

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Im getting random data from my database using aggragate but its converting its array properties to string

```
 const book = await Book.aggregate([
    {       
        $sample: { size: 6 } }
    ]);
```

desired result

> {"title": "Analysis, Vol I",
> "author": "Tao, Terence",
> "genre": [
> "mathematics"
> ],}

Result im getting

> "title": "Analysis, Vol I",
> "author": "Tao, Terence",
> "genre":
> "mathematics"

How can I fix this? I want get array from the genre so that I can loop through it

Comment: could you please show us where you get that result?

Comment: @Ifaruki Im using postman for accessing the api and getting the data in my mongo db database, I also have other api for getting the books and they work fine, im getting an array of genre, but when using aggregate for random books in database, im getting a string of genre. I think aggregate is converting it to string for me,